# php ldap_get_values() for more than 1 value

Tags: php

I am using the `ldap_get_values` function in a script that uses LDAP authentication.

My question is:

Is it possible to pull more than one `value` (as the name suggests 'values') in one `query`? Or does it have to be  looped over (which to me doesnt really make sense as it would mean querying AD multiple times which would be inefficient?

My current function is this:

```
ldap_get_values($ds, $entry, "mail");
```

Which pulls the mail value.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-values.php) it returns an array which you would loop over.

Comment: I understand that it returns an array but I need to add more than 1 attribute for it to pull this information like this: `ldap_get_values($ds, $entry, "mail,uid,cn"); ` but this returns an error `ldap_get_values(): Cannot get the value(s) of attribute Decoding error` because my syntax is wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see. Let me take a look at the PHP source code and see what I find.

Comment: I have just found this which may have the answer I am looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-entries.php

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I would need to use another property in the ldap_search function like this:

```
$attributes_ad = array(
    "displayName",
    "description",
    "cn",
    "givenName",
    "sn",
    "mail",
    "co",
    "mobile",
    "company",
    "displayName"
    );
            $sr = ldap_search(
$ds,
    "cn=users,dc=servername,dc=com", 
    "(uid=$username)", 
    $attributes_ad
) or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
$entry = ldap_first_entry($ds,$sr);
$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

//Now, to display the results we want:
for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
{
      // to show the attribute displayName (note the case!)
      echo $info[$i]["mail"][0]."<br>";
      echo $info[$i]["uid"][0]."<br>";
      echo $info[$i]["displayname"][0]."<br>";       
 }
```